# Скрипт для формы поиска

Tags: html, php

У меня есть форма поиска. Нужен файл `search.php`, ну или помощь в написании)

Вот собственно сам код формы:

```
<div>
<form method="post" action="search.php">
<input type="text" name="q" value="" /> <input type="submit" value="Искать" /><br />

Выберите тип файла:<br />
<select class="inp" name="tf"><option value="">Любой</option>
<option value="vid">Видео</option>
<option value="vid.3gp">Видео: 3gp</option>
<option value="vid.avi">Видео: avi</option>
<option value="vid.mp4">Видео: mp4</option>
<option value="img">Картинки</option>
<option value="img.jpg">Картинки: jpg</option>
<option value="img.jpeg">Картинки: jpeg</option>
<option value="img.png">Картинки: png</option>
<option value="img.gif">Картинки: gif</option>
<option value="img.wbmp">Картинки: wbmp</option>
<option value="mus">Музыка</option>
<option value="mus.mp3">Музыка: mp3</option>
<option value="mus.wav">Музыка: wav</option>
<option value="mus.mid">Музыка: mid</option>
<option value="mus.amr">Музыка: amr</option>
<option value="mus.mmf">Музыка: mmf</option>
<option value="thm">Темы</option>
<option value="thm.thm">Темы: thm</option>
<option value="thm.nth">Темы: nth</option>
<option value="thm.sdt">Темы: sdt</option>
<option value="mid">Приложения/Игры</option>
<option value="mid.jar">Приложения/Игры: jar</option>
<option value="mid.jad">Приложения/Игры: jad</option>
<option value="mid.sis">Приложения/Игры: sis</option>
<option value="mid.apk">Приложения/Игры: apk</option>
<option value="mid.zip">Приложения/Игры: zip</option>

</select><br/>
Искать в:<br />
<select name="dt">
<option value="0">Все</option>
<option value="1">Новинки</option>
<option value="2">За последний месяц</option>
</select>
</form>
</div>
```

Comment: У меня есть шнур питания, помогите собрать радиостанцию.!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

примерно так:

```
    if(isset($_POST['q']) AND isset($_POST['tf']) AND isset($_POST['dt']))
    {
        if(empty($_POST['tf']) AND empty($_POST['dt']))
        {
            // тип файла и категория - любые
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['tf']))
        {
            // тип файла - любой
        }
        elseif(empty($_POST['dt']))
        {
            // категория - любая
        }
        else
        {
            // поиск по типу файла и категории
            // select * from table, where file=$_POST['tf'], and where catalog=$_POST['dt']
        }
    }
```